# Reference request on books allowed?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

I have seen several of them. But I just wanted to make sure I could ask for reference requests rather than losing a lot of reputation afterwards.

So are reference requests allowed in the math forum?

Comment: Related: [Book recommendation opinion based?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20965/book-recommendation-opinion-based) and [Is it appropriate to ask for references and book recommendations?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21514/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-for-references-and-book-recommendations)

Comment: See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005) as well.

Comment: A Question can be good or bad despite being a request for references.  Note that reference requests are requests for published works (possibly peer-reviewed works) about specific topics or results.  Recommendations for "good books" on a broad subject (logic, calculus, analysis, statistics, etc.) need considerable context to be taken seriously, regardless of whether a "reference request" tag has been attached.